# my AMD Phenom II X6 1065T don't activate TurboCore anymore

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have a HP pavillon p7 1044 at home with a AMD Phenom II X6 1065T.

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02972447&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=5080737

When I have it I install the software overdrive from AMD. When I did heavy 3D render , I hear the fan going faster and see in overdrive the processor going from 2900mhz to 3400mhz. But I start to get some problem with my hard one week ago where it's not reconized it when connected in the first SATA port , so I plug it in the second port and it's working well now. I put a bigger video card and a bigger powersupply in it too. But now the turbocore seam to don't working anymore. No increase in Mhz ( stay at 2900mhz ) when work loaded and don't hear the fan goes faster. I don't see any option in the bios setup menu.

The new video card is a old one , Nvidia Geforce 8800 GTX ( but better then the integrated one , I can play Diablo3 now ! ). The powersupply is a 550 watts from ThermalTake.

I want to see if another solution exist before starting to play in the hardware again.
Somebody know or have somethings to suggest ?

thanks a lot !

Comment: What is the CPU core temperatures being detected as?

Comment: 48-49Celcius after a 4hours of hard working